# htaccess : %{HTTP_HOST} not interpreted in redirect destination

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to setup some redirections in my htaccess file using the tag %{HTTP_HOST} in the destination URL but it does not work.

Example :

```
RedirectPermanent /test http://%{HTTP_HOST}/fr/news/test?
```

I want to use the %{HTTP_HOST} tag because i want my htaccess file to work on my local machine and on my production server, without needing to update the htaccess.

In Firefox, when I enter http://www.example.com/test, the address in the address bar is converted  to http://%{HTTP_HOST}/fr/news/test, like if the tag was not interpreted ! The page remains white.
In Chrome, nothing happens, neither in the address bar nor in the page.

Isn't it possible to use the %{HTTP_HOST} tag in the destination of the redirect ?

thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%{HTTP_HOST} Variable is part of mod_rewrite, you can not use it in mod_alias,

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^test/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/fr/news/test? [L,R]
```